# Not enforcing fixed width font family

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, fonts, fixed-width

Currently the `code` blocks have a list of fixed width fonts specified in the style sheet, and I'd like them to just be `monospace` instead. I know I can override it with stylish on firefox to use Droid Sans Mono, but I think it would be better if the font choice wasn't enforced in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can't use `font-family: monospace` due to massive, hairy bugs in Safari / Chrome / WebKit regarding them. Although these bugs are of the "this is how *we* interpret the spec" type, it's worth pointing out that no other popular browser interprets them this way.*

http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/103606
http://webkit.org/blog/67/strange-medium/

> The moral of the story: be wary of tt, pre and font-family: monospace.

If you want it fixed, file bugs against WebKit. There is no way I'm willingly going back to that particular `font-family: monospace` hell.

Edit: thanks to Ludwig's answer, we now have [a valid workaround](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2010/02/12/fixed-monospace-sizing/)! Thank you!

<sub>* I call this "Opera Syndrome".</sub>

Comment: Opera is not involved, is it?

Comment: Fair enough (15 chars).

Answer (score 7):

There is a simple proven solution and [Eric Meyer has an excellent article about it](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2010/02/12/fixed-monospace-sizing/).
The solution is not new (Wikipedia deployed it in December 2009) and 
Eric has done incredible work in verifying it.

While I can absolutely sympathize with Jeff when he says he's not willingly to go back to the `font-family: monospace` hell I still think this solution should also be deployed on SO and sisters.

My proposed fix is:

```
font-family:Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace, serif;
```

Comment: "Really. Alone among the browsers I tested, Safari goes back to doing the resizing when you provide a generic fallback to your specific family." YEP

Comment: the magic trick here is adding `,serif` at the end by the way.

Comment: The trick is adding ``,monospace, serif``. What you quoted from the article is the problem, the solution is right below:
"Really! Even in Safari! And in all tested browsers, it falls back to a generic monospace font **at the requested size**.."
Emphasis mine.

Comment: And yet, that doesn't address the original question - which was rightfully declined. He wants just font-family: monospace so he doesn't have to do any work to use his pet monospaced font.

Comment: @AnonJr: No, you don't need `font-family: monospace` to use a custom monospace font. `font-family: [lots of stuff], monospace, serif` is perfectly OK. And this is not about 'pet' fonts. What if you don't have Consolas on your platform and the fallback renders terribly?

Comment: From the OP (emphasis mine): "I know I can override it with stylish on firefox to use Droid Sans Mono, but **I think it would be better if the font choice wasn't enforced in the first place**." You are right that you don't need `font-family: monospace;` to use a custom font, and the OP states as much. He just doesn't want the stack to specify a font so the site will render with the browser defaults and obviate the need for him to actually use something like a custom stylesheet, stylish, GM, etc. This question is not about fall-backs for missing fonts.

Comment: @ludwig this hack may be broken in new versions of Android, based on some of the reports I am now getting.

Comment: Confirmed to be broken in Chrome on the Samsung S4 mini. Fun facts: Chrome on other Androids works just fine, and so do other browsers, including the stock browser, on the very same S4 mini. But I don't mind the lack of the fixed-width rendering that much, so well...