# Code blocks do not use a fixed width font on Android

Tags: support, mobile-web, android

When browsing from my HTC Droid Incredible, running Android 2.2 w/ Sense, code blocks are not fixed-width.

*Minor* issue, no doubt.

[image: example]

Comment: Minor or not, I'd still like to see this fixed on my HTC Incredible too. :)

Comment: seems to be a known bug in the Android browser: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11356

Comment: I'm seeing variable-width fonts using Chrome 29 on Android 4.3 today. Is this a possible regression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pre style defines a LOT of standard fonts that work across Windows, Linux, and Mac.

```
font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, 'Lucida Console', 'Liberation Mono', 
             'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', 'Courier New', 
             monospace, serif;
```

*none* of those fonts work on the Android browser? I dare say that is not a bug in *us*.

edit: also possibly related to
[Not enforcing fixed width font family](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33945/not-enforcing-fixed-width-font-family)

Comment: Not sure when this changed, but [all is fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zj7Jx.png) on Android 2.3.x and 4.x today. (That is, unless lines need to be wrapped, and one expected that all browsers use the same width, [which they don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables/73567#73567), of course. But that still uses fixed width fonts then.)

Comment: thanx for this :)