# Code blocks don't show up as monospace text on the mobile website on Android

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, mobile-web

I'm using a Nexus 5. When browsing the mobile website on the browser (Chrome) with "Request Desktop Site" turned off, I get this appearance for code blocks (on [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251176/1204143)):

> [image: unformatted code blocks]

This is rather unfortunate because it makes code (and especially tables like the above picture) very hard to read.

The Chrome browser clearly supports preformatted text, because it shows up correctly if I request the desktop site. (But then, it is more difficult to use the site).

Comment: That may not be *code*, but a *quote* instead. Could you provide a link to the actual post?

Comment: I think this is an [Android issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11356), as [pointed out by balpha](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67432/code-blocks-do-not-use-a-fixed-width-font-on-android#comment161975_67432).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome for Android has a [sketchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015854/monospace-css-not-working-in-chrome-for-android) [history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67432/code-blocks-do-not-use-a-fixed-width-font-on-android) of bad support for [monospace](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11356) and [font-family](https://gist.github.com/bear454/6982879) in general. I've substituted the old simple "monospace" we used with "Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace", which is what we use on the desktop site, which Chrome for Android seems to handle correctly.

This will be out in the next builds (`2253` on meta and `1611` on the network).

Comment: Assuming that meta.so picked up this change, it doesn't seem to have worked. I'm using a Nexus 5, stock Android 4.4.4.