# Code style of overlength oneliners

Tags: support, code-formatting

Sometimes there are one or two lines of code which are overlength, like this

```
set10 = "UPDATE " + databasenow + " SET 1= '" + 1.ToString + "', 2= '" + 2.ToString + "', 3= '" + 4.ToString... and so on and so forth
```

in most cases I think it's better to have it at a glance instead of trying to scroll and reconstruct it in ones mind, thus I format it with backticks.

`set10 = "UPDATE " + databasenow + " SET 1= '" + 1.ToString + "', 2= '" + 2.ToString + "', 3= '" + 4.ToString... and so on and so forth`

However, such edits are reversed from time to time by other users, so:

How to deal with such code lines/snippets?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't have overlength one-liners in your code ;-)

Comment: @jandvorak I never have. I never have code with overlength lines at all since the mousewheel's target is the vertical scrollbar mostly.

Comment: That is VB.NET code.  Arbitrarily breaking the line makes it invalid, so of course users will try to fix it.  Post proper code.

Comment: @Uphillluge & _ ftw.

Comment: @uphillluge [This](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22423609/revisions) is the revision that made me ask the question. I thought it is evident, that there is no "real" line break in the code

Comment: Ugh, I'll never understand why SO users post a question and use a completely inappropriate code snippet when they can just as easily post the real code.

Comment: @uphillluge It is not *a completely inappropriate code snippet*. I took it randomly cause the oneliners I encounter can be in any language. Actually that was part of the question, whether the backticks could be used to indicate that it is a single line and no line breaks were made..

Answer (score 5):

Backticks don't get syntax highlighting, they're really only meant for very short pieces of code inline in a sentence. For actual statements or blocks, always use proper code blocks.

Try to split long lines where it makes sense. Different people will have different styles of course, just like for regular coding styles, so what you select might not always get accepted.

In this case, try something like:

```
set10 = "UPDATE " + databasenow
      + " SET 1= '" + 1.ToString
        + "', 2= '" + 2.ToString
        + "', 3= '" + 4.ToString
        + // ad libitum
```

(Some languages might not support that, or require some syntax at the end of the line to indicate that it's a continuation - don't touch the code if you're not familiar with the language anyway.)

Comment: [Almost](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zlnUd.png)... ;-)

Comment: (: Fixed @Arjan, but without a fixed-width font, there is no hope. :(

Comment: Yeah, that fixed font is a Chrome-on-my-Samsung thing. Other browsers and Chrome-on-other-droids *do* have fixed fonts. (See [Not enforcing fixed width font family](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33945/not-enforcing-fixed-width-font-family).) Still then: no scrollbars on the mobile theme, but code is wrapped and always shown. [Nick wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98776/stack-exchange-mobile-launched/103249#comment272038_103249): *Two-finger scrolling doesn't work reliably (or at all) on some of the Android devices I've tested with. Makes wrapping the only real option.*"

Comment: That said, [try again](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kMtwU.png) ;-)

Comment: An [A for effort](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zifv7.png) ;-) (And yeah, this is the small screen of a HTC Wildfire S, but I also have an Xperia S10 mini lying around somewhere, with an even smaller screen...)

Comment: I... surrender.

Comment: :-) Just to be sure: I very much agree with your answer.