# Code blocks not using fixed-width font family in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-norepro, code-formatting, fonts, linux

Code blocks are not rendered using a fixed-width font in Firefox 99 64-bit Ubuntu.

A screenshot of the issue for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543541/how-can-instantiated-javascript-objects-communicate-with-eachother) (left is using Chrome, and right is using Firefox):

[image: Screenshot of bug]

The issue is caused by this here. In https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css line 646:

```css
font-family:var(--ff-mono);
```

It would be fixed if replacing it with:

```css
font-family:Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace, serif;
```

---

Related:

- [Not enforcing fixed width font family](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33945/479836)
- (possibly) [We're Migrating our JavaScript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372590/479836)

Comment: This is probably limited to Ubuntu, and other linux based OS's, as this works perfectly fine on MacOS. Adding the linux tag for that.

Comment: I can't reproduce it in Firefox 99 on Ubuntu 64-bit. It shows as your left screenshot, the Fonts tab in the Inspector says that it uses Liberation Mono for the code block (and Liberation Sans for the other text). In your screenshot on the right the text also shows much larger than it should be. Maybe your issue is caused by a general font problem in your Firefox setup?

Comment: It's not clear why that change would fix it for you. It is a CSS variable which is set properly to the monospace font set. Is your browser not properly pulling in that variable and calculating the value? Does manually changing the CSS in your dev tools actually change it to the proper font on the page?

Comment: @animuson I think it just fit ok if it is changed at the variable. I tried playing with changing the various font variants in the variable. At some point I got it working after removing a bunch of font alternatives but could not pinpoint a sspecific one that was causing this issue. The only one that always works is `monospace`. I also checked I have the very same issue with GitHub which uses the same font selection for code blocks.

Comment: Marking this as norepro since it appears to be something specific to your system.

Comment: I don't observe the problem in Firefox 99.0 on [Ubuntu 18.04.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver).

Comment: Can you add the link to the specific example to the question? Can you add the Ubuntu version (there is a time correlation with the new [Ubuntu 22.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)) [LTS](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) (Jammy Jellyfish) released seven days ago)? (For example, from `cat /etc/os-release` on the command line.)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum https://stackoverflow.com/q/12543541/7939871

Comment: Do you use  Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Using Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: After trying `fc-cache` to rebuild the font cache without success, I finally migrated to Ubuntu 22.04 and the issue is gone.

Comment: And the issue is back